# External product of two groups has no subgroup of index two

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Thought:**
From the statement given here , [The number of subgroups of index two in $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3414842/516174).
We can conclude that $``$A group has no subgroups of index $2$ iff it is generated by squares of its elements.$"$ $.......(1)$

*Lemma: For every  $G_1$ and $G_2$, $(G_1\oplus G_2)^2=G_1^2 \oplus G_2^2 $*.
 These $G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite groups.

> Statement:  If $G_1$ and $G_2$ are groups with no subgroups of index $2$ , then $G_1 \oplus G_2$ has no subgroups of index $2$.

**Question(s):**

> $(1)$ Please give a proof for the Lemma. $(2)$ Can we prove the above statement by using this Lemma and $(1)$ (How)?

**My work:** For $(2)$, If we take $G_1=A_4$ and $G_2=H$; where, $A_4$  is alternating group with four symbols and $H$ be any group of odd order say $h$ so that its clear that $A_4 \oplus H$ has no subgroup of order $6h$. Therefore the above statement holds for this setting.For $(1)$, I was trying to show that one is contained in the other one but didn't get anything as I got stuck in between.

Comment: That question you linked is about finite groups only, not about all groups.

Comment: @LeeMosher Thanks for correcting me. I am going to edit my question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $G_1\oplus G_2=\{(x,y):x\in G_1, y\in G_2\}$.
Now, $$(G_1\oplus G_2)^2=\{(x,y)\cdot(x,y):x\in G_1, y\in G_2\}=\{(x*x,y\Delta y):x\in G, y\in G_2\}=\{(x^2,y^2):x\in G_1, y\in G_2\}=G_1^2\oplus G_2^2$$, where $\cdot, *$ and $\Delta$ are the respective group operations.

By the question and answer you linked, it is clear that a group has no subgroups of index two iff $G^2=G$. Thus, if $G_1, G_2$ have no subgroups of index two, then $G_1^2=G_1$ and $G_2^2=G_2$ which implies $(G_1\oplus G_2)^2=G_1^2\oplus G_2^2=G_1\oplus G_2$, thus giving us that the direct product of two groups also has no subgroups of index two.