# Number of subgroups of $C_2^n$ of index $2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Let $G=C_2^n=\langle x_1,\dots,x_n \rangle$ the elementary abelian group of order $2^n$. There is an isomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n \to G$, $a=(a_1,\dots,a_n) \mapsto x^a=x_1^{a_1}\cdots x_n^{a_n}$.

$\chi_u : G \to \{\pm 1\} $, $x^a \mapsto (-1)^{ua}$ is a homomorphism for every $u \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$, so $\ker \chi_u$ is a subgroup of $G$ of index $2$ for every nonzero $u \in (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^n$. There are at least $2^{n}-1$ different subgroups of $G$ of index $2$.

How can I see, that there are exactly $2^{n}-1$ subgroups of $C_2^n$ of index $2$?

Perhaps in this particular case there is an easier way to see the statement than here: [The number of subgroups of index two in $G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3414842/the-number-of-subgroups-of-index-two-in-g)

Comment: Suggested approach: let $H_0 = (\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^{n-1}$ embedded into $G$ in the first $n-1$ coordinates, and let $H$ be any index-$2$ subgroup of $G$. By vector-space change-of-basis facts, there is a group automorphism $\phi\colon G\to G$ such that $\phi(H_0) = H$. Then show that $H$ is the kernel of $x^a \mapsto (-1)^{\phi(0,\dots,0,1)a}$.

Comment: Another approach : a subgroup of index $2$ is the same as a $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$- hyperplane, which in turn is the same as a non-zero linear form $G\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$. Since the dimension of $\mathcal L_{\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z}(G,\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)$ is $n$ we have the result.